# Error CS8107: Feature 'tuple equality' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.3 or greater

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0, c#-7.3

I have the lastest Visual Studio 2017 version

[image: My Visual Studio version]

I have tried:

- Specifically set C# Version project to 7.3
  [image]
- Specifically set C# Version project to **latest**
- to manually modified the .csproj of the project (to latest and to C# 7.3)
- Updated the Visual Studio version
- Used .NET Framework 4.7 instead of 4.7.2
- to install the ValueTuple Package (which I uninstalled right after)
- to install Microsoft.Net Compilers package

After all these, my project still does not seems to compile in C# 7.3 because when I try to compare two tuples in the debugger, it prompts this error message:

[image: The error message I get when I use the debugger]

which translates to: **Error CS8107: Feature 'tuple equality' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.3 or greater**

And here is my code:

```
 (CRiverGameState, int, bool) osti;
 bool canRaise = _gameState.GetLstAllowedActionsForCurrentPlayer().Contains(ActionsPossible.Raise);
 (CRiverGameState, int, bool) riverKey = (riverGameState, (int)_boardType, canRaise);

 foreach(var tabarnak in CDBHelper.PRiverAllGameStatesFoldStats.Keys)
 {
   if (tabarnak.Item1.PID == 2592 && tabarnak.Item2 == 1089 && tabarnak.Item3 == false)
     osti = tabarnak;
 }
```

I'm out of ideas. Why is my project compiled in C# 7.0 instead of C# 7.3 ?

Comment: please do not post images of code.  instead post as text and format the text using the editing tools

Comment: Make sure you have enable C# 7.3 for all configurations (Debug, Release, ...). [4 ways to enable the latest C# features](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/08/24/4-ways-to-enable-the-latest-c-features)

Comment: I changed the image for code, sorry for this.

Comment: I tried the 4 ways and it doesn't work unfortunately. I also did it for all of the configurations.

Comment: My project is contained in a solution that contains other projects, but those other projects are all updated to C# 7.3 aswell. I have tried the "Directory.Build.props" thing, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Just to be clear, you've updated *all* of your projects to use 7.3?

Comment: Yes, all of them have the .NET framework version 4.7 and the c# version 7.3 for all configurations (debug, release). I even tried to put a Directory.Build.props for the solution specifying the language version 7.3 with no success.

Comment: It should be as simple as adding `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in the csproj file. You could get around it by using `tuple1.Equals(tuple2)`

Comment: I have created a new project with a simple WinForms application and it still doesn't work. I'm clearly not using C# 7.3 on my computer for some reason... I think this is related to my version of MSBuild for some strange reason

Comment: I found it! See my post below

Comment: What was the root cause?

Comment: @JulienCouvreur there's no bug, at least not what the OP thinks as a bug - the project compiles but the *debugger expression doesn't*. The *default* language version is the latest major, in this case C# 7. That's the language used by the debugger for expressions, even though the project targets a different version. The project's language version doesn't affect the debugger's. In a multi-project, multi-version solution that's *not* a bad decision.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the clarification. We actually have a bug tracking this (debugger should use LangVersion=latest): https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/28486

Comment: @JulienCouvreur oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debugger version uses C# 7.0.

Your project is using C# 7.3, but the debugger is using C# 7.0.

If you do:

```
bool result = (osti == riverKey); // This will return true, but not in the debugger
```

This will work.

Comment: You should EDIT your question instead of posting as an answer, which it isn't.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21428030)

Comment: This IS the answer. If you ever encounter this error you'll know why you're getting it. I thought my project wasn't using c# 7.3, but it turned out that it was using c# 7.3 and that the debugger wasn't using c# 7.3 when I use the "watch" variable. However the project is compiled in c# 7.3.

Comment: I don't know why my debugger uses c# 7.0, and I don't care, atleast I know that my project is running under c# 7.3. This is the answer. Now if the person wants to update his debugger to c# 7.3, well that wasn't the question.

Comment: You can report to Microsoft as a bug https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzszcehe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Jonathan you *should* care and fix the question. The project *does* compile, contrary to what you posted `my project still does not seems to compile in C# 7.3`.  You should change the text and title to ask `why doesn't tuple comparison work in the Watch Window` at least.

Comment: @Jonathan as for this being a bug, it's probably not. The *default* language version is the latest *major* version of the language. That is C# 7.0, not 7.3. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699125/how-to-change-visual-studio-2017-default-language-version-for-all-projects) explains this and is probably a good answer for this question. I suspect the *real* question you'd like to ask is `How do I set the debugger's language version to latest minor instead of default?`

Comment: "Error CS8107: Feature 'tuple equality' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.3 or greater" only occurs when the project compiles in C# 7.3, but is not running under c# 7.3 in the watch variables. This is a good question because the person that is looking for this type of answer doesn't know that his debugger (watch variables) version is not the same. So changing the title of the question to "How do I set the debuger's language version to lastest minor instead of default" is wrong because the person that is asking the question doesn't know that this is what's happening.

Comment: Also, the link you posted, I already did that (the "Directory.Build.props" thing). In the first post of the question, you can look at the comments, you'll see that another person suggested to do that and it didn't work. My project is set to c# 7.3 in everything, and I also tried to put everything to "latest", it never worked out. I'm pretty sure it is a bug but I'm too lazy to report it.

Comment: You seems to not have read the whole post or you read it really quickly because you suggest me to use "lastest minor instead of default" when clearly in the first image we can see that I already did that, and in the 1st and 2nd bullet point also suggest that. I wrote "My project doesn't seem to compile in C# 7.3 **because when I try to compare two tuples in the debugger, it prompts this error message (image here)**. I didn't say I was right or anything, I just said that my project doesnt seems to compile in c# 7.3 because of the watch variable thing error. It was just a observation.

Comment: So, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue albeit with higher versions ie CS8370 C# Feature is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version {1} or greater.
I found getting the very latest updates via the standalone Visual Studio Installer cleared it right up.
Note: I got a non-descript error using the Check for Updates option from the Visual Studio Help menu.